# Creating a FIFO List in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I work in Transportation/Freight and we have these things called "PRO" numbers or freight bill numbers, which you can think about as and Invoice and Tracking number for a shipment.

Our carriers send us blocks of 2,000 sequential PRO #s at a time. Previously, we'd just work from Excel and mail-merge basically just printing off the barcode and changing the cell's color to keep track of what's been used.

We want to automate this process now in the system that creates the shipping documents. Creating the list of PRO #s in MySQL is easy. The problem is that each PRO # can only be used once, but we have multiple people generating shipping documents at any given time.

How can I retrieve a single PRO # from the database and be certain I've only ever used it once?

I'm open to other solutions that are not `SELECT` based. Maybe I can game the `AUTO_INCREMENT` system MySQL uses and use an `INSERT` based system? That would possibly be easiest to implement but I think it could possibly cause problems and could possibly get quite messy and tedious to maintain.

EDIT:
This is a Multi-Tenant system and transactional as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-odbc/en/connector-odbc-usagenotes-functionality-last-insert-id.html), you can do something like this

```
mysql> CREATE TABLE autoinc (id MEDIUMINT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, sample INT, PRIMARY KEY(id));
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.34 sec)

mysql> INSERT INTO autoinc VALUES(NULL, 5);
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.05 sec)


mysql> SELECT last_insert_id();
+------------------+
| last_insert_id() |
+------------------+
|                1 |
+------------------+
1 row in set (0.01 sec)

mysql>
```

[EDIT - in response to OP's comments]

"To start with an AUTO_INCREMENT value other than 1, set that value with

`CREATE TABLE or ALTER TABLE, like this: 
mysql> ALTER TABLE tbl AUTO_INCREMENT = 100;"`

Also, [this](http://www.percona.com/blog/2011/11/29/avoiding-auto-increment-holes-on-innodb-with-insert-ignore/) might help

Comment: Well, yes, I'm aware of `last_insert_id()`, however these #s don't start at one, rather 356348789 or whatever the next free starting number is, and then when they're exhausted, we get a new block which will start several thousand #s away from our last used value. This is where using an `INSERT` system becomes more complicated and problematic and difficult to maintain.

Comment: I ended up using a method built on the behaviour of MyISAM Compound PKs and Auto Increment getting reset to the highest value inserted into the column automatically. Thank you!